# Download file from external website with InAppBrowser - Ionic

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on android app and I use Ionic

I want to open external link with InAppBrowser and allow the user to download file from a link inside this site...

But when I click on download link inside this site, nothing really happens...

Some help please
This is my code:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser, public network:Network, public dialogs:Dialogs, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {}
example(){
    const browser = this.iab.create('myURL','_blank',{location:'no',zoom: 'no'});
    browser.show();
}
```

Comment: Please show me the code you've been doing so far.

Comment: ok i add the code in the description :)

Comment: This tutorial will help you to solve your problem https://www.onetruecode.com/inappbrowser-ionic-3-example-with-some-useful-properties/

Comment: Thank u soooo much bro :D